# Is there a way to transfer data from ldap server to MySQL (or Elasticsearch)?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, ldap

I am very new to DB.

Is it possible **to transfer data from LDAP server to mysql**?

Also is it possible **to transfer data from LDAP server to elasticsearch**?

I am using **Grafana** and trying to integrate it with LDAP data (if possible directly)

Since Grafana can connect with MySQL and Elasticsearch, I want to transfer data from LDAP server (ldif , csv, or any) to **MySQL** or **Elasticsearch**.

If anyone had done this before, could you give me some tips on how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that with slapcat: https://serverfault.com/questions/435261/ldap-export-and-import

To import into mysql or similar, you'll have to understand the dump format and put it into mysql.